# Auto Enabling The macOs Extension from Swift Code

Tags: swift, macos, macos-sierra, finder, findersync

I am writing a custom App for macOs with a **FinderSync Extension**. The code is written using swift. After installing this app; user need to manually enable the the FinderSync extension of my App from Systems Extensions. Anyone knows how to make it **automatically enable the FinderSync extension** of custom app after installation. Is there any Xcode capability to make it auto enable?

Comment: Put up some code where you want to perform autoSync